# Stack data-structure ran out of space

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stack

I am working on some data-structure and algorithms problem from one of the courses on Coursera. The first problem that has been given to us is that of "Brackets matching feature" for a text editor. I will give you a few short examples to tell what the desired feature is:

```
Input: () or [] or {}[] or [()] .......
Output: Success

Input: {
Output: 1 (As first unmatched opening bracket and position is 1)

Input: {[}
Output: 3 
Explantin: The bracket } is unmatched, because the last unmatched opening bracket before it is [ and 
not {. It is the first unmatched closing bracket, and our first priority is to output the first 
unmatched closing bracket, and its position is 3, so we output 3

Input: foo(bar[i)
Output: 10
Explanation: ) doesn’t match [, so ) is the first unmatched closing bracket, so we output its 
position, which is 10.
```

So, basically our priority is to point out first-unmatched closing bracket which doesn't have an opening bracket before it or closes the worn opening bracket. Some of the constraints for the implementation are:

```
Memory Limit: 512MB
Time Limit(C++): 1 Sec
Length of the input string can be from 1 to 10^5
```

My current implementation looks like this: (I basically pass all the opening brackets to the stack along with their position in the string)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>

struct bracket_data {
char next;
int pos;
};

int main(){

std::string text;
getline(std::cin,text);
std::stack <bracket_data> char_stack;
int unmatched_pos = 0;
char top_val;

for(int pos = 0; pos < text.length(); ++pos){
    char next = text[pos];
    struct bracket_data data;

    //std::cout << "Next char in string is: " << next << "\n";

    if(next == '(' || next == '[' || next == '{') {
            if(pos == text.length() - 1)
                unmatched_pos = pos+1;
            else{
                data.next = next;
                data.pos  = pos;
                char_stack.push(data);
                std::cout<< "Data pushed is " <<data.next<< " and pos is " <<data.pos<<"\n";
        }
    }
    else{
        if(!char_stack.empty()){
            top_val = char_stack.top().next;
            //std::cout << "Current top val in the stack is "<<top_val
            //<<"\n";
        }

        if(next == ')' || next == ']' || next == '}'){
            if(next == ')' && top_val == '('){
                char_stack.pop();
                if(pos == text.length() - 1)
                    std::cout <<"Success\n";
                //std::cout << "Round brackets match found\n";
            }
            else if (next == ']' && top_val == '['){
                char_stack.pop();
                if(pos == text.length() - 1)
                    std::cout <<"Success\n";
                //std::cout << "Square brackets match found\n";
            }
            else if (next == '}' && top_val == '{'){
                char_stack.pop();
                if(pos == text.length() - 1)
                    std::cout <<"Success\n";
                //std::cout << "Curly brackets match found\n";
            }
            else{
                unmatched_pos = pos + 1;
                //std::cout << "No brackets match found\n";
                std::cout <<unmatched_pos<<"\n"; 
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        else{
            if(next == '(' || next == '[' || next == '}'){
                unmatched_pos = pos + 1;
                std::cout <<unmatched_pos<<"\n" ; 
                exit(0);
                //std::cout << "A single unmatched bracket found\n";
            }
            else
                //std::cout << "Char found!\n" ;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation passes 53 of the given 54 test cases where it is failing for the last ([54th](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jkysnsyrbSWGNsrF4l3_4jT64N9L1IXq/view?usp=sharing)) test case which has got in total 10^5 characters in the string.

When I print what all values are going to the stack, I see that the `stack.push()` operation does not go beyond

```
--------------------------------
Data pushed is ( and pos is 4090
Data pushed is { and pos is 4091
Data pushed is [ and pos is 4092
Data pushed is [ and pos is 4093
```

As far as I can see, it seems like I ran out of stack space to push more characters to. So my question is in two parts:

1. Is it because of the way I have gone about implementing the problem? (which I believe can be an issue, but can't think of a reason why it would run out of stack space)
2. Can I forcibly increase the size of the stack that I am using here?

Comment: You can reduce the footprint of your stack if you store the positions only. (The characters are already stored in `text` and storing their positions you know where.) The input size is limited to 10000. So, you can use `std::uint16_t` to store positions. (It has range [0, 65535] what's really sufficient for this.) A `std::stack` wraps by default a `std::deque`. Using a `std::vector` instead may improve a bit further. ([C++ benchmark – std::vector VS std::list VS std::deque](https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque.html)).

Comment: This is a reviewed version of your code which you may check out: [**demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9779784f891a840c). (I tried to improve it further by pre-allocating the vector but coliru seems to be down temporarily.)

Comment: @Scheff Thank you for looking into my issue. I tried running the version that you had written on coliru, but it is also not able to return the correct answer for test case 54. Upon debugging, it seems like the last value it is writing to stack is at position 4095. Now it seems to me that there definitely is some issue with the way the implementation is done by me or do you think it is a machine specific problem?